# How to copy a .txt file from sdcard to my app res/raw folder

Tags: android

how to copy my text file in my app at (res/raw) folder from sdcard. thing about is not at 
stackoverflaw about copy a file from sdcard to my app.
i am not getting anything else from Google so please help me a perfect answer.

Comment: You **can't**. But you can do the opposite: **raw => sdcard**.

Comment: It's impossible to do that, but why would you want to anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this help you:

Android `.apk file` is **Read Only.**
So the directory structure which are in that apk file follows the same.. 
No one can write files or make changes at runtime as ***Assets folder are not Writable...*** 
That's why You can't make any changes in `/asset folder` at runtime...
We can only read file from it (means we can copy files which are available in `asset` to `any internal storage or /sdcard` but reverse of it is not possible).